# get at least two matches from json

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON

```
{
"people": [{
        "games": [
            "destiny",
            "horizon",
            "fifa",
            "cuphead"
        ],
        "name": "Cartman"
    },
    {
        "games": [
            "fifa",
            "pes"
        ],
        "name": "Kyle"
    },
    {
        "games": [
            "cuphead",
            "destiny"
        ],
        "name": "Stan"
    },

    {
        "games": [
            "pokemon",
            "metroid"
        ],
        "name": "Clyde"
    },
    {
        "games": [
            "fifa",
            "metroid",
            "pes"
        ],
        "name": "Butters"
    }

]
```

}

and I need to get the users that have at least two games in common so for this JSON the result will be:

Cartman and Stan plays destiny and cuphead

Kyle and Butters plays fifa and pes

Note: Clyde will be not in the results because theres only one game match with other player

I thought about two workarounds

1- have a dictionary using two tags (covering all possibilities) as a key and filled it if it doesnt exist and after other key match that way I will know that theres already two matches

2- get the first user compare it against the others and it if matches at least two printed it then continue with the next one and compare with the rest and so on

Any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: You forgot to post the code you already have ..?

Comment: What have you already tried? Is there a bug in code you have already made or are you wanting us to write this code for you?

Comment: why `games` and`tags`?

Comment: its games thats a mystipo I already edited with two ways I figure out to solve it but im not sure what will be the best thanks

Answer (score 0):

An *approach* with reducing the games/peoples by checking if only one exists and delet then the respondend part of the other object.

It returns more items than one, but more than two.

For getting a result, you could eliminate the one with two parts and adjust the rest.

```js
var object = { people: [{ games: ["destiny", "horizon", "fifa", "cuphead"], name: "Cartman" }, { games: ["fifa", "pes"], name: "Kyle" }, { games: ["cuphead", "destiny"], name: "Stan" }, { games: ["pokemon", "metroid"], name: "Clyde" }, { games: ["fifa", "metroid", "pes"], name: "Butters" }] },
    peoples = {},
    games = {},
    change = false;

object.people.forEach(function (person) {
    person.games.forEach(function (game) {
        games[game] = games[game] || {};
        games[game][person.name] = true;

        peoples[person.name] = peoples[person.name] || {};
        peoples[person.name][game] = true;
    });
});

do {
    change = false;
    Object.keys(games).forEach(function (k) {
        var keys = Object.keys(games[k]);
        if (keys.length === 1) {
            delete peoples[keys[0]][k];
            delete games[k];
            change = true;
        }
    });
    Object.keys(peoples).forEach(function (k) {
        var keys = Object.keys(peoples[k]);
        if (keys.length === 1) {
            delete games[keys[0]][k];
            delete peoples[k];
            change = true;
            return;
        }
    });
} while (change);

console.log(peoples);
console.log(games);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I tried something like this, but the thing its that I need to know which persons are playing the same games (at least  two or more)

Comment: and what was the problem?

Comment: that I dont know after getting the hash structure (game: array of users) how to iterate to find the two matches

Comment: view the `Object.keys ...` part for getting the keys and assigned arrays.

Comment: that gets the game and all the people playing it but how should I know that stan and cartman plays cuphead and destiny (at least two games in common)  thats what I need to know sorry if  I wasnt clear

Comment: thanks for the update this really helped me to get the solution